# Compare two rows in same table (Duplicates)

Tags: t-sql

I would like to compare rows where i have same name and surname and check if data is the same before i will delete the duplicate. All data is in one table  client.

Example:

```
value name      surname
2     James     Bond
**3   James     Bond**
2     James     Bond
1     Bonnie    Bond
1     Bonnie    Bond
```

I would like to return only values that are not matching. So only James Bond. How to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT value, name, surname
FROM tablename
GROUP BY value, name, surname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

Comment: this is not answer to question.

Comment: @ravenaot I just read the question again and the answer looks like a reasoble answer. Problably you should search the mistake in your question

Comment: @ravenaot Then you need to clarify the question.